# How do I use the yfinance API in Python to get today's DJI open?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

How do I use the yahoo finance API to get the day's DJIA open each day?
when I use

```py
import yahoo_finance
dji = Share('dji')
DJIA = dji.get_open()
print(DJIA)
```

it gives error `<urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>` on the second line

Comment: Why are you expecting 'yahoo' to be in the namespace when you've imported yahoo_finance?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], the entire error message, and a clear description of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [yfinance package](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/), then you can get the last day's open this way.

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download(tickers = "dji", interval = "1d", period = "1d")
print(data["Open"][0])
```

Comment: 1) why did I get `[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed` before the number?
2) it gave a different number than just checking up today's DJI open in the [Yahoo! Finance website](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EDJI/)